# Getting "IllegalStateException: FragmentManager has not been attached to a host" when trying to call replaceFragment method from different fragment

Tags: java, android

## The Problem

I currently have one MainActivity that has a fragmentManager which works as intended when clicking on the buttons associated with the MainActivity (the navigation bar). However, when I click buttons in a fragment, I get a "java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager has not been attached to a host" error. After reading the documentation and looking for solutions online, I have tried:

- Creating an instance of MainActivity and calling the function
- Rewriting the replaceFragment method in the profileFragment
- Using the activity.getSupportFragmentManager() method
- Using the parentFragmentManager() method

All of the these solutions returned the same error. Is there something I am missing in the documentation? Any help would be greatly appreciated, please let me know if you need any further information.

### MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.palestra;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.palestra.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{
    private ActivityMainBinding binding;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());
        replaceFragment(new profileFragment());
        
        //the replaceFragment() method works here
        binding.navBar.setOnItemSelectedListener(item -> {
            if (item.getItemId() == (R.id.profileIcon)){
                replaceFragment(new profileFragment());
            }
            else if (item.getItemId() == (R.id.addFriendIcon)){
                replaceFragment(new searchFragment());
            }

            return true;
        });


    }

    public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment){
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.homeFragment, fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

### profileFragment.java

```
package com.example.palestra;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher;
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestOptions;
import com.github.dhaval2404.imagepicker.ImagePicker;
import com.example.palestra.MainActivity;

import kotlin.Unit;
import kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1;


public class profileFragment extends Fragment {
    private ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> imagePickLauncher;
    private Uri selectedImageUri;



    public profileFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    String getWorkoutName(String workoutName){
        return workoutName;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        imagePickLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
                result -> {
                    if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        Intent data = result.getData();
                        if (data != null && data.getData() != null) {
                            this.selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                        }
                    }
                });

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final String TAG = "onCreateView";
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
        ImageButton benchPressButton = rootView.findViewById(R.id.benchPressIcon);
        ImageButton squatButton = rootView.findViewById(R.id.squatIcon);
        ImageButton deadliftButton = rootView.findViewById(R.id.deadliftIcon);
        ImageButton profilePicture = rootView.findViewById(R.id.profilePictureButton);
        MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();

        //replace fragmentMethod does not work here
        benchPressButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try{
                    mainActivity.replaceFragment(new workoutFragment("Benchpress"));
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    Log.d(TAG, "***" + mainActivity + " " + e + "***");
                }
            }
        });

        squatButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try{
                    mainActivity.replaceFragment(new workoutFragment("Benchpress"));
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    Log.d(TAG, "***" + mainActivity + " " + e + "***");
                }
            }
        });

        deadliftButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                try{
                    mainActivity.replaceFragment(new workoutFragment("Benchpress"));
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    Log.d(TAG, "***" + mainActivity + " " + e + "***");
                }
            }
        });

        profilePicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "clicked profile picture");
                ImagePicker.with(profileFragment.this).cropSquare().compress(512).
                        maxResultSize(512, 512).createIntent(new Function1<Intent, Unit>() {
                            @Override
                            public Unit invoke(Intent intent) {
                                imagePickLauncher.launch(intent);
                                Log.d("***onClick***", "ImageURI: " + selectedImageUri);
                                if (selectedImageUri == null) {
                                    //do nothing
                                }
                                else{
                                    Glide.with(profileFragment.this).load(selectedImageUri).apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform())
                                            .into(profilePicture);
                                }
                                return null;
                            }
                        });
            }
        });

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return rootView;
    }

}
```

### MainActivity.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="      Palestra"
        android:textSize="34dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-medium"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/homeFragment"
        />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/navBar"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/title"/>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_bar_menu"/>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

### fragment_profile.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".profileFragment">
    <include
        layout="@layout/profile_box"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        />
    <include
        layout="@layout/exercise_select_menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

### Components of fragment_profile.xml

#### exercise_select_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="#272928">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/benchPressIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_picture_button"
        android:src="@drawable/benchpress_transparent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/squatIcon"
        android:contentDescription="@string/benchDesc"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/squatIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_picture_button"
        android:src="@drawable/squat_transparent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/benchPressIcon"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/deadliftIcon"
        android:contentDescription="@string/squatDesc"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/deadliftIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_picture_button"
        android:src="@drawable/deadlift_transparent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/squatIcon"
        android:contentDescription="@string/deadDesc"/>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

#### profileBox.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#272928"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/profilePictureButton"
        android:contentDescription="@string/profilePictureDesc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/add_image_foreground"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_picture_button"
        android:scaleX=".80"
        android:scaleY=".80"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="-260dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/aboutMeText"
        android:layout_width="270dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:hint="@string/profileAboutMe"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:text="@string/aboutMe"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/profilePictureButton"
        android:maxLength="256"
        />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

### Logcat

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.palestra, PID: 9680
java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager has not been attached to a host.
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1668)
at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:341)
at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:306)
at com.example.palestra.MainActivity.replaceFragment(MainActivity.java:47)
at com.example.palestra.profileFragment$3.onClick(profileFragment.java:98)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:8043)
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:8020)
at android.view.View.-$$Nest$mperformClickInternal(Unknown Source:0)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:31850)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:230)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:319)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8893)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:608)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1103)
```

Comment: Can you check the logcat where error line appear.

Comment: @TicherhazFreePalestine I added the logcat to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you are creating a new MainActivity instance, but you don't need to do this since you are accessing the new MainActivity, not the one that already exists. When creating a new MainActivity, try using the context of an existing one, either by passing it through the constructor or using the `getActivity()` method.

Comment: Thank you! I passed the mainActivity to the fragment and the app now works as intended.

Comment: I'm glad that it worked out for you. Good luck with programming!